# Laravel valet not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-valet

I use OSX El Capitan and PHP 7. I followed the installation guide so I install Laravel Valet version v1.1.3 successfully. I ping foo.dev or any.dev then the terminal prints

```
"64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.116 ms"
```

Everything is ok. My directory `/User/mickey/Sites` is added to Valet's paths. I created a Laravel 5.2 project named blog, then run the project with `php artisan serve` ok but when i accessed url blog.dev on the browser, the browser said

> This site can’t be reached, blog.dev refused to connect. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

I don't know what is the problem with my installation. Thanks in advance!

Comment: any chance you have a firewall?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte: I already turned off firewall

Comment: flush the DNS, `dscacheutil -flushcache`

Answer (score 24):

You needn't run `php artisan serve` as Valet runs Caddy in the background.

Here're a few troubleshooting points.

- Ensure that you don't have Apache (or anything else running on port 80)

  `sudo apachectl stop`
- Ensure that Valet is running

  `valet start`
- Ensure that PHP was installed with FPM

  `brew uninstall homebrew/php/php70`

  `brew install homebrew/php/php70 --with-fpm`

Comment: I run the `php artisan serve` in the `blog` directory just to make sure the project is working as normal. I also installed php7 with fpm and start valet, stop Apache but still can't access to blog.dev.

Comment: When i run `sudo lsof -i :80`, only `caddy` is appear.

Comment: Have you removed any references to `*.dev` from your `/etc/hosts` file? Perhaps blog.dev is directing to another IP, perhaps Homestead or somewhere.

Comment: Here is my hosts file: 
`127.0.0.1       localhost`
`255.255.255.255 broadcasthost`
`::1 localhost`

Comment: Stopping Apache worked for me. Had some wacky configuration running that I totally forgot about. Thanks!

Comment: Great stopping apache is worked for me also, by default the valet is parking to mamp when you stop serving apache it works :) Thanks

Answer (score 16):

After trying everything I found on the internet (including [this one](https://github.com/laravel/valet/issues/326#issuecomment-281254202) which worth to try) for me the solution was to change valet's domain to `test`.

`valet domain test`

So I have no idea if the mentioned reinstall was needed or not but I know that I could `ping` or even `curl` my `.dev` sites but could not open them in any browser (Chrome nor Safari). Then I tried to set domain to `.app` but that did not work either. In the browsers I was redirected all the time to `https` even after running `valet unsecure`.

But then changed domain to `.test` and suddenly it started to work. I'm not sure what is the real issue here and why is this but I'm okay with it since it works again.

I've also read that `.dev` is not good any more because it's an official TLD and so reserved. ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains))

Comment: Same as you Mr. I tried all the things here and there. But every thing was failing for me. And finally i read your comment here. Coz i had also changed my domain to *.dev from *.test
And then I thought let's give it a try. So i changed it back to the *.test and it worked. Like you sir, i don't know why it behaved. But your comment did work for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I had nearly the same issue of Laravel Valet not working after installing via Homebrew on macOS 10.13 "High Sierra".

The problem I encountered was that DNSMasq would respond to queries, but Nginx would not handle the responses on port 80.

Attempting to connect to the site in a Terminal session would result in the following error:

```
$ curl -IL http://example.test/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to example.test port 80: Connection refused
```

*I had recently upgraded from macOS 10.2 "Sierra" to 10.13 "High Sierra", so I suspected my Homebrew environment and configuration that was brought by the Migration Assistant could be at fault.*

While following the troubleshooting advice here and [elsewhere](https://gist.github.com/adamwathan/6ea40e90a804ea2b3f9f24146d86ad7f#gistcomment-1993250), **what eventually solved my problem was to completely uninstall and remove Valet along with its dependencies (PHP, Nginx, DNSMasq, etc):**

```
$ rm -rf ~/.valet
$ brew unlink nginx && brew remove nginx
$ brew unlink php56 && brew remove php56 && brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies php56
$ brew unlink php72 && brew remove php72
$ brew unlink dnsmasq && brew remove dnsmasq
```

With a clean slate, I was able to successfully [install Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/valet#installation):

```
$ brew update
$ brew install homebrew/core/php
$ composer global require laravel/valet
$ valet install
```

I then setup a new development domain:

```
$ valet domain test
$ valet park ~/Sites
$ mkdir ~/Sites/example && cd "$_"
$ valet link
$ echo "Hello, world" > ~/Sites/example/index.html
```

With Valet installed, I verified everything was working:

```
$ valet --version
$ sudo nginx -t
$ ping -c 4 example.test
$ curl -IL http://example.test/
$ valet open example
```

After doing all of this, I had a 100% successful working Laravel Valet environment.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I can now solve this one for you. The Self Control fix worked as a temp fix for me so you may be in luck as I've found a permanent solution for me!

I once had a httpd setup which I followed a guide to install. This came with some baggage as the guide got you to forward 127.0.0.1 port 80 to port 8080.

Try this anyway Go > Go to folder...

/Library/LaunchDaemons/

The file in my case was called co.echo.httpdfwd.plist which I just needed to delete and then restart my Mac. See my question for more info [Laravel Valet not working. 127.0.0.1 Connection Refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38338710/laravel-valet-not-working-127-0-0-1-connection-refused/38340185#38340185).

Let me know how you get on!

Comment: This is not a solutions, just a "hack" for making it work again... I will not restart my Macbook because there is a way to fix this the "right" way.

Comment: Clearly haven't read the whole answer correctly? Self Control was a hack to fix it yes. The actually reason why it wasn't working is because there was a file called co.echo.httpdfwd.plist within my /Libray/LaunchDaemons/ directory that forwarded 127.0.0.1:80 to port 8080 as the apache setup listened on 8080. Self Control hacked it as it overrides these files by adding its own files to the LaunchDaemons folder. Expand on your issue and I will try and help you fix it..

Answer (score 1):

in my case, I encountered this after putting my mac to sleep but fixed it by running:

> valet stop

and then

> valet start

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by starting self-control app. I don't know the reason but you can try to download and start this app to resolve this problem.